# How to check whether the launch is first launch and include tutorial-LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to create a tutorial of my game for the first launch of game. Next time tutorial should not occur.
For this, I created a boolean value to be stored in preference to indicate whether the launch is first or not.

My singleton preference class is included here:

```
public class FirstLaunchNotifier {

    public static final FirstLaunchNotifier INSTANCE = new FirstLaunchNotifier();

    private final Preferences prefs;

    private static final String LAUNCH_KEY = "launch";
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "TMS";

    /* if false->first launch with tutorial.else if true->no tutorial */
    private boolean launchBoolean;

    public FirstLaunchNotifier() {
        prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREF_NAME);
        launchBoolean = prefs.getBoolean(LAUNCH_KEY, false);
    }

    public void saveLaunchState() {
        launchBoolean = true;
        prefs.putBoolean(LAUNCH_KEY, launchBoolean);
        prefs.flush();
    }

    public boolean getLaunchBoolean() {
    //  System.out.println("launch::: "+launchBoolean);
        return launchBoolean;

    }
```

in my gamescreen class,currently I have `update()` method that I am calling inside `render()`.

For tutorial part of first play of first launch,I want to call a separate update method `tutorialUpdate()`.
I am confused of how to get this launchBool value properly with this `update()` and `tutorialUpdate()`.

Once the tutorial is finished,game should come back to normal play.Before that `saveLaunchState()` should be called so that `launchboolean` become true to indicate that first play is over and no more tutorial required.

This is how I calls update() right now in render().

```
case RUN:
    update(delta);
break;
```

Do i need to get the boolean value like this?

```
if(FirstLaunchNotifier.INSTANCE.getLaunchBoolean()) {
     update(delta);
     tutorial update();
}else{
     update(delta);
}
```

Which is the proper way to do this?

Comment: if update(delta) is in both the if, and the else, then you can break it out of the if completely. I'd recommend exploring ways to do this in a polymorphic way though.

Comment: where and when do you call `saveLaunchState();` ? Besides I recommend do only skip the tutorial when the player did finish it at some point. Starting app 2nd time does not mean he has played it at 1st start.

Comment: Syntax of singleton class is wrong.

Comment: What is the exact syntax for singleton class here?@AbhishekAryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FirstLaunchNotifier` as a singleton.

```
public class FirstLaunchNotifier {

    private static FirstLaunchNotifier instance;
    private  Preferences prefs;
    private boolean launchBoolean;

    private static final String LAUNCH_KEY = "launch";
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "TMS";

    private FirstLaunchNotifier(){

        prefs= Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREF_NAME);
        launchBoolean = prefs.getBoolean(LAUNCH_KEY, true);
    }

    public static FirstLaunchNotifier getInstance(){

        if(instance==null){
            instance=new FirstLaunchNotifier();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void saveLaunchState(boolean state) {
        launchBoolean=state;
        prefs.putBoolean(LAUNCH_KEY, launchBoolean);
        prefs.flush();
    }

    public boolean getLaunchBoolean() {
        return launchBoolean;
    }
}
```

You can get object of `FirstLaunchNotifier` by `FirstLaunchNotifier.getInstance()` and do calculation according to your requirement like

```
if(FirstLaunchNotifier.getInstance().getLaunchBoolean()) {
     update(delta);
     tutorial update();
}else{
     update(delta);
}
```

And when user completed tutorial part then just call

```
FirstLaunchNotifier.getInstance().saveLaunchState(false);
```